# Print smallest integer from file using awk custom function?

Tags: text-processing, awk

`awk` function looks like this in a file name `fun.awk`:

```
{
print small()
}
function small()

{
a[NR]=$0

smal=0

for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
{
if( a[i]<a[i+1])

smal=a[i]

else

smal=a[i+1]

}
return smal
}
```

The contents of `awk.write`:

```
1
23 
32
```

The `awk` command is:

```
awk -f fun.awk awk.write
```

It gives me no result? Why?

**update**

```
{

print f()
}
function f()

{


if(NR==1){s=$0}


if($0<p)

{s=$0}

{p=$0}

 { return s}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions of your code will run the `small` function on every line of the input file. If you want to find the smallest number in the entire file, you need to run the function only once and at the end, after the entire file has been processed. Your updated function looks like its working and printing the correct output three times but that's only because the smallest number is on the first line. If you run it on this file:

```
$ cat awk.write
10
9
8
```

You will get this output:

```
awk -f fun.awk awk.write
10
9
8
```

This is because every time the function is run, the current line's number is smaller than what has been saved, so it is printed. You need to use an `END{}` block and run the function there:

```
function small(){
    for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)
    {
      ## If smal is not set or if it is greater than a[i]
      if(smal=="" || a[i]<=smal)
        smal=a[i]
    }
return smal
}
{
    ## NR is the current line number. This saves the current line
    ## in the array a.
    a[NR]=$0
}
## This will be executed only after everything has been read
END{
    print small()
}
```

I also generalized to use `NR` instead of `3` so it can work on any number of lines. You could further simplify to just:

```
{
    if(small=="" || $0<small){
    small=$0
    }
}
END{print small}
```

Which is the same as this one-liner:

```
awk '(small=="" || $0<small){small=$0}END{print small}' awk.write
```

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive reply. In your comments you mentioned ` ## NR is the current line number. This saves the current line` but is `$0` a record buffer it contains the entire contents. The first record is `NR=1` please clarify?

Comment: @asad `NR` is the line _number_ and `$0` the line's _contents_. So, if the first line is `foo`, `[NR]=$0` will run `a[1]=foo`. I'm just using `NR` as an easy way of getting array indices.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax in the if-clause is wrong, use:

```
if( a[i]<a[i+1]){
  smal=a[i]
}else{
  smal=a[i+1]
}
```

But, it will print the value for every line.

---

A better solution for you problem would be:

```
sort -n file | head -1
```

- This sorts the file contents numerically ascending, and `head` prints only the first line.

Or if it must be `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1{s=$0} $0<p{s=$0} {p=$0} END{print s}' file
```

- `NR==1{s=$0}` if it's the first line, set the `s` variable.
- `$0<p{s=$0}` if the current line is smaller than the previous one, set the `s` variable to that value.
- `{p=$0}` for each line, set the `p` (previous) variable for the next iteration.
- `END{print s}` when all line are processed, print the value of `s`.

---

**Edit:** all that in a function, would look:

```
awk 'function f(){ if(NR==1){s=$0} if($0<p){s=$0}p=$0} {f()} END{print s}' file
```

Comment: thanks, so this code with `awk` can be placed into function as well?

Comment: i want to do as part of fucntion not in-line awk

Comment: I tried it doesn't work also there is a missing `{` in `p=$0`

Comment: also, my way of using it as function is different `awk -f fun.awk awk.write`

Comment: i revised the code for function see main question in update section but problem is that it prints x3.